# Find GCD of two polynomials: $x^5 + 4x^4 + 3x^3 + x^2 + 4$ and $x^4 + 4x^3 + 4x^2 + 4$ in field $\mathbb{F}_3$ and in field $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, factoring, gcd-and-lcm

I was able to find only one way of doing that: Euclidean algorithm for polynomials. But is there any "simpler" way to find their GCD (if it is important, the answer in both cases is 1 by my calculations)? Because for me it took a lot of time to find quotients. Maybe some method of finding it fast? Thanks!

Comment: The way to find it fast is the Euclidean algorithm. The other way involves factoring the polynomials, which is (in general) slower.

Comment: But if we call the polynomials $p$ and $q$, respectively, then $xq-p$ is particularly simple.

Comment: Making any progress?

Comment: I guess not. Too bad.

Comment: @GerryMyerson as I described in question, I did solve this one. The question was If there is a better way of doing that in this particular case.

Comment: Right. So: did you look into my hint about $xq-p$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh, sorry, now I understand. I tried it, works pretty well, thanks!